# Why the sets in this answer open?

Tags: metric-spaces

I have a quick question about an [old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253858/find-two-disjoint-open-sets-u-v-such-that-a-subseteq-u-b-subseteq-v-where) on the website want to prove

> Let $A, B$ be two disjoint closed subsets of a certain metric space $(M,d)$.
>
> 1. Show that there exist disjoint open subsets $U, V \subseteq M$ such that $A\subseteq U, B\subseteq V$.

In the answer, the author claims

> Let $U = \{x | d(x,A) < d(x,B)\},V =
> \{x|d(x, A) > d(x, B)\}$. Since $d(x, A), d(x, B)$ are continuous functions, U,V are open sets

I am trying to figure out why the continuity of the distance functions  tells us that these sets are open.

I tried considering complements but to no avail. Then I tried open balls but I quickly got worried for things with bad regularity.

**Question:** Could someone elaborate on how the sets $U$ and $V$ are open?

Comment: If $f\colon X \to Y$ is a map between topological spaces, then by definition (or by characterization, depends on the approach), $f$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$ whenever $U$ is open in $Y$. Apply this with $X=M$, $Y=\Bbb R$ and $f(x) = d(x,A) - d(x,B)$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Just to clarify, here I would take the preimage of the negative axis (excluding zero) and of the positive axis (excluding zero) to be my two sets \(U\) and \(V\) correct?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly this. Heuristically, the set of points that are strictly closer to $A$ than to $B$ is open because, because "strict" is an open condition